# EF Core - Save partial only if it does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a model which has quite a few references governed by some foreign keys. I receive the entity as a JSON payload:

```
{
  "Person": {
      "Name": "John",
      "Age": 24,
      "Email": "john@contoso.com"
  },
  "RandomText": "This is my text"
}
```

Lets imagine this maps to a model which looks like this:

```
class Message {
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; } // contains guid / name / age / email
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

With an equivalent two tables, one for the person and one for the Message which has a reference to the person. These two are obviously 1 (Person) to many (Messages)

This illustrates my setup.

In order to automatically sync this I want to do some validations / checks on the data I receive, e.g: If the person exists, then attach that persons Guid, if the person does not exist, generate a Guid, save the person, then save the text.

My model is a little more complex, but follows the same pattern:

```
class Meeting {
public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
public Location Location { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
public DateTime? BookedAt { get; set; }
public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
public bool WasCancelled { get; set; }
public bool WasNoShow { get; set; }
public bool WasAdhoc { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Extended> Extended { get; set; }
public bool WasEnded { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndedAt { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<MeetingPurpose> Purpose { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<MeetingRoomMeeting> MeetingRooms { get; set; }
public Guid? DeliveryId { get; set; }
public virtual Delivery Delivery { get; set; }  
}
```

`MeetingRoomMeeting` and `MeetingPurpose` are join tables which merely maps a many to many relationship:

```
public Guid MeetingRoomId { get; set; }
public virtual MeetingRoom MeetingRoom { get; set; }

public Guid MeetingId { get; set; }
public virtual Meeting Meeting { get; set; }
```

Again the point is, I have some data which *may have been saved once* already - I need to ensure if this is the case, and not save it again. Is there any pattern to this, or is it simplest to do it with raw queries, or maybe rip apart the class "Meeting" from the component classes and validate / save them individually?

Comment: If you validate before adding with a query such as `if(db.message.Any( t => t == AddingMessage)` This is what i consider (clean), another one would be to just add the new entity inside a `try{}catch{}` So Entity will try to add the new object, and will fail in the case it already exist, then you can manage this case in the catch{}.

Comment: But my best way would be to use `Message mes = db.Message.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Guid == addingMessage.Guid) if(message != null)` It will return null if it isint already in, but will take the object if it exists. Therefore : update the existing object, or add the unexisting object. That's the real thing, because there is no such thing as `db.Message.addIfNotExists(object)`